Domain Wide Delegation failing in dev but not in local env
I've set up Domain Wide Delegation for my Firebase service account so that I can use the google calendar API to add attendees to a meeting in a cloud function.
This is all working in my local environment with the firebase emulator but when I deployed the code to Firebase, I began getting this error:

Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide
Delegation of Authority.

I checked, and the Client IDs match in my local env and the dev env.
What could be causing this to fail in the cloud env but not my local env?

Hi Douglas. By chance are you loading the service account locally by doing something like GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service-account.json firebase emulators start and then using the googleapis library in your cloud function code?

Yes. That's exactly what we are doing.
